# What node does 11 point to?

Tags: mathematics, graph-theory, number-property

If we included 11 in the diagram below, which node would it connect to?

[image]

Hint 1

> Above is a directed graph showing a consistently-applied relation between numbers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> 6, because eleven has 6 letters

Comment: Matt Parker did a [whole video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYKn0yUTIU4) on that.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That video was the inspiration for making this puzzle!