# Which node(s) does 16 connect with in this simple graph?

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, graph-theory, computer-science

If we add 16 as a node to the graph below, which node(s) will it connect to?

[image]

Hint 1

> the [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) tag is indicating knowledge of computer science concepts, not external 'data' related to the graph.

Hint 2

> This puzzle is derived from, but very much different from, [another puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97419/what-node-does-11-point-to).

Hint 3

> Nodes 8, 11, and 12 are not included because they are completely disconnected from each other and the other nodes from 0 through 15. They're still disconnected from the rest of the graph when we include 16.

Hint 4

> The relation has something to do with comparing strings.

Hint 5

> *An* edit distance (metric) is involved.

Comment: Would including 8, 11, and 12 give too much away?

Comment: @RobPratt I've added information about those nodes as Hint 3 if you want it

Comment: Not a hint, but it looks like [Big Hero 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Hero_6_(film)) is waving at us.

Comment: If hint 4 is the case instead of the definition of simple graph(no loop) then I must say it should be connected with 15 as they have a long string :D

Comment: Hint 4 and the definition of a [simple graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html) are consistent. [Cycles](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html) are allowed, but [loops](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphLoop.html) are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two nodes are connected if and only if

> the English names of the numbers have [Levenshtein_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of 3. E.g. 'five' and 'four' - the f is the same, other letters have to be replaced. 'seven' and 'ten' - 1 letter needs to be replaced, 2 added or removed, so edit distance 3.

Therefore, 16 is connected to

> 13 ('sixteen' - 'thirteen') only; 15 is 'too close' with an edit distance of 2.