# Which node(s) does 0 connect with in this simple graph?

Tags: mathematics, graph-theory, number-property

If we add 0 as a node to the graph below, which node(s) will it connect to?[image]

Hint 0

> I've made [another puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97419/what-node-does-11-point-to) before, which may give clues if you begin to bore.

Hint 1

> If your hair you begin to tear out, then perhaps you should check [this out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97421/which-nodes-does-16-connect-with-in-this-simple-graph).

Hint 2

> My hints usually start at 1, but this once let's have fun.

Comment: Hi Galen! I was wondering if you could comment on the discussion in El-Guest's answer.  Thanks! And thank you for the cool puzzle :)

Comment: @stux I've commented on what I'm guessing you'd like me to address. I'm glad you enjoyed the puzzle. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should connect to

> Nothing, because all nodes are connected to other nodes that share a word.

Note that

> **one** connects to twenty-**one**, seventy-**one** and **one** hundred, but not to seventeen. None of these nodes have “zero” in their names, and so it is not connected.

Comment: Were the hints helpful?

Comment: Hint 1 helped work out the difference between my first answer and my second answer, @Galen

Comment: (*spoiler*) based on this answer, shouldn't 7 and 17 be connected?

Comment: Technically yes, but I just took them as two separate examples of graphs — ie. to help us note clearly that 17 was not connected to 71, 21, 1, or 100. Not sure if that was OP’s intention as well.

Comment: Ah, no no no, what I mean is that "seventeen", and now that you point it out, "seventy-one" should both be connected to "seven" because they both connect that word.  I should've posted this on the original posting but I was trying to hide spoilers a little.

Comment: Ah I see — maybe it’s comparing singular, non-hyphenated parts of words — “seventeen” is a different word from “seventy” in “seventy-one” and from “seven”

Comment: Oh! That would make sense!  I can't tell if that is also the case from the rest of the graph.  I've placed a comment in the question itself, hopefully we can get some feedback from the OP. :)

Comment: @El-Guest [rot13](https://rot13.com/) Lrnu, lbh'ir tbg gur evtug vqrn. Gur fgevatf ner fcyvg ol fcnpr naq ulcura, ohg ng yrnfg bar fcyvg fgevat zhfg or rknpgyl rdhny (fhofgevat vf abg rabhtu) gb fngvfsl gur eryngvba.

Comment: You can think of the entire collection of nodes and edges in the diagram as a single graph, or as separate graphs since they'd also be subgraphs of the complete diagram. I guess you never know with a puzzle, but I'd personally *prefer* to make separate diagrams to show graphs with different relations.

Comment: That is to say, every subgraph is a itself a graph.

Comment: Yep — that makes sense to me. Great puzzle, I enjoyed it!